# get contracts entries based on documents expiration_date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query in laravel 8:

```
DB::table('contracts')
  ->leftJoin('documents', 'contracts.id', '=', 'documents.contract_id')
  ->whereNotNull('expiration_date')
  ->whereMonth('expiration_date', '01')
  ->whereYear('expiration_date', '2022')
  ->select('documents.contract_id', 'documents.is_contract', 'documents.expiration_date')
  ->get();
```

**Contracts** - **Documents** (one to many)

**expiration_date** is in Documents table and is nullable.

If the contract has 2 documents with expiration_date filled then it will return both entry (for the same contract).

I want to get the last entry for expiration_date from documents (only one entry for the contract)

ex: If a contract has 2 documents with expiration_date set ... I want to take only the last expiration_date value for that contract.

How can I do that ?

Comment: I am not an expert, but `SELECT MAX(expiration_date) GROUP BY contract` seems like a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have proper Models and Relationship between `Contracts` and `Documents`, and `documents.expired_at` is a correct MySQL date format, you could try the [latest()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest) method:

```
Contracts::with('documents', function($query) {
    $query->latest('expired_at')->first();
})->get();
```

This code is for the "Eloquent" way, and not for the "Builder" way that you uses. And only includes the example for the "take only the last expiration_date value for that contract" part of your question.

Comment: and what about whereMonth, whereYear ? I need to see only the contracts that expire in January 2022

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :latest will get the latest expiration_date.

```
DB::table('contracts')
      ->leftJoin('documents', 'contracts.id', '=', 'documents.contract_id')
      ->latest('expiration_date')
      ->whereNotNull('expiration_date')
      ->whereMonth('expiration_date', '01')
      ->whereYear('expiration_date', '2022')
      ->select('documents.contract_id', 'documents.is_contract', 'documents.expiration_date')        
      ->get();
```

Comment: getting the same result .... the last 2 entries in this case point to the same contract id (the last 2 entries are from the same contract)

Comment: does not make sense. I need all the contracts not first() :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using any_values it seems to work

```
DB::table('contracts')
  ->leftJoin('documents', 'contracts.id', '=', 'documents.contract_id')
  ->whereNotNull('expiration_date')
  ->whereMonth('expiration_date', '04')
  ->whereYear('expiration_date', '2022')
  ->select('documents.contract_id')
  ->selectRaw('max(documents.expiration_date) as expiration_date, any_value(documents.is_contract) as is_contract, any_value(documents.description) as description')
  ->groupBy('documents.contract_id')
  ->get();
```